# Cannot retrieve text file using ajax from static directory with expressJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

So this may be a dumb problem but I've been trying to load a text file from a static directory by using some simple ajax and then insert it into an html page. 
I'm not really sure why the thing's giving me a 404 when I make the request, I thought the static directory would allow this. I'd like to avoid having to make individual app.get() for every file in that folder.
I've tried various ways to declare the path to the static folder but nothing seems to work, I might just be missing something though.

Server side is Node with ExpressJS, client side is just typical javascript/jQuery. The text file is literally just two paragraphs of lorem ipsum.
Here's the relevant portions of code:

the ajax request for the document where I want to insert:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'articles/latest.txt',
        dataType: 'text',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#latestPost').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

and the express static that I'm trying to serve.

```
app.use(express.static('/articles'));
```

EDIT (solution found):

I'm an idiot and I fixed it, using this fixed everything and now stuff loads fine. Thanks makozaki for the help anyway.

```js
app.use('/articles', express.static(__dirname + '/articles', {index: 'false'}));
```

Comment: Is file `articles/latest.txt` served corretly? When pasting path in your browser can you see file content?

Comment: I can't access it, get a "Cannot GET /articles/latest.txt" when trying to access directly.

Comment: If you start your server locally path would be: `localhost:<some port>/<path to static server route>/articles/latest.txt` so example url you should check should be: `localhost:8000/static/articles/latest.txt`.

Comment: I've tried pretty much every combination of paths I could think of and none of them work, I'm starting to wonder if I just screwed up and the express static isn't done right or something.